# How to get base url in CodeIgniter 2.*

Tags: php, codeigniter

In config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

In View

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url(); ?>css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

`=> Error: Call to undefined function base_url();` Help me

Comment: you forget echo  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?> try this its work for you.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To use `base_url()` (shorthand), you have to load the `URL Helper` first

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

**Or** you can autoload it by changing `application/config/autoload.php`

**Or** just use

```
$this->config->base_url();
```

Same applies to `site_url()`.

Also I can see you are missing `echo` (though its not your current problem), use the code below to solve the problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: if i only using $this->config->base_url("localhost/mysite"); in my controller but still get error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()` what is wrong here? I using CodeIgniter_2.1.4

Answer (score 9):

I know this is very late, but is useful for newbies. We can atuload url helper and it will be available throughout the application. For this in application\config\autoload.php modify as follows -

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to load the URL Helper in order to use `base_url()`.  In your controller, do:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
echo base_url();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just load helper class

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add url helper in config/autoload

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'file', 'html'); <-- Like This
```

Then you can use base_url or any kind of url.