# Codeigniter Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am stuck with what seem to be quite common. I have seen plenty of this questions so i know that is relates in some way to the others, however i still can not figure out why i am getting this error
 I have latest codeigniter 
My controller class

```
class AddLog extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function occupierLog_add(){
    $this->load->view('LogViews/LogIncident_Occupier/AddLogIncident');     
}
public function add_log(){
    $newLog = $this->input->post(null, true);
    var_dump($newLog);
}
```

}

my Index html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="http://localhost/Concierge/application/controllers/Logs/AddLog.php/AddLog/occupierLog_add">Log Incident - Occupier</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see My Controller AddLog is inside contollers/Logs directory. In one of the methods i am trying to call view which is located in views/LogViews/LogIncident_Occupier/...

Comment: Your link is completely wrong, you do not call a controller directly! (and not in _that_ way) You need to call it using a URL, please refer to the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) for basic routing

Comment: @DamienPirsy i have looked into that, however i do not fully understand this

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503302/how-to-get-base-url-in-codeigniter-2-0-2

Comment: @Anand No, that has nothing to do with OP's problem, base_url() and being able to create a valid url to a controller are 2 different things

Comment: @DamienPirsy will this be correct ?? http://localhost/Concierge/index.php/Logs/addlog/occupierlog_add .. it works as it should however is that correct way of doing  ?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Note that your "Addlog" controller now needs to be inseide the `Controller/Logs` folder (unless you routed the request).

Comment: @DamienPirsy i haven;t routed it and its inside Logs folder. However i can now see what routing is, so will play around with it later on :)

Comment: I would suggest renaming the Logs folder since there is already a Log folder present in CI installation which logs all error generated by application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what version of CI are you using?
because in 2.0 the controller super class is CI_Controller
and in CI version 1 the controller super class is Controller