# Codeigniter how to properly use base_url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a little trouble with base_url in codeigniter, let's say if I don't set my $config['base_url'] in the config/config.php file, calling `base_url` will produce [::1], this is not what I want, I want it to return localhost, so I set `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost'`, yup it return `localhost/bla/bla`

when accessed locally, HOWEVER if I access my project remotely from another computer, it DOES keep returning 'localhost' too while what I want is to return the base_url as in the ip address of the server (i.e 192.168.1.8 etc).

I am very sure CI team has thought this through and has a special solution or parameter in the base_url however I wasn't able to find it or I am not searching enough. Anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: put server ip in $config['base_url'] = 'host ip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign base_url dynamically using host

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. "| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!"

Comment: Thanks mate! Your solution is actually what I'm looking for, however I'm not sure if this is good practice ?.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As per Codeigniter's documentation this should NOT be used in production. @Charas

Comment: @Callombert Thanks! then can you suggest me what is supposed to be used in production ?

Answer (score 1):

To use base_url(), you have to load the URL Helper first

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or you can autoload it by changing application/config/autoload.php

Or just use

```
 $this->config->base_url();
```

Same applies to site_url().

and use like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

you can follow this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503302/how-to-get-base-url-in-codeigniter-2)